# applicationWillEnterForeground Check

Tags: ios, swift

In my application ios I have an if that checks if there is internet connection before running the app, if it is offline it sends a screen to retry, the code is as follows below:

```
        if CheckInternet.Connection(){

            let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/")
            let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
            webView.load(request)
        }

        else{
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OffViewController") as! OffViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        }
```

I want to check the connection also when it comes back from the background for first, I read something about applicationWillEnterForeground, but how would the if checking inside that func? On android it is easier to do that but in ios n I have idea

Comment: It should be better if you can be more clear about what you want. If you want to do something when your app is coming to foreground from background state, you should add observer for .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground.

Comment: you can add an observer for that notification `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)`  and add the necessary code in the assigned selector `@objc func willEnterForeground(_ notification: Notification) { \\yourCodeHere
    
    }`

Comment: Its Work! thanks Leo